# Knockout.js encrypt and decrypt front-end model data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

When utilizing knockout.js and knockout.mapping I pass the model data through to the view and store it as a Javascript variable using "@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));".  My question is this, what would be the most efficient way to encrypt and decrypt the array of model data, preventing the user from being able to view this via the front end?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you want to simultaneously hide and expose the data? If the client needs it then it has to be readable so you can't hide it behind a bit of crypto. If the client doesn't need to see it then don't give it to them.

Comment: Model data has to be used and passed through as a front-end JavaScript variable, from here knockout utilizes the encoded model property values as its view model data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if its sensitive data dont send it to the client put it in the server side user session

if it its that important to send it to client then use cookies, encrypt the cookie and save it on the client side, upon reception of request, extract, decrypt the cookie.

now if you really really want your current code to work then encrypt your model property like

```
public class Sensitive{
 public String Name{  
   set{
    this.Name= YourEncryptionFunc(value)
   }
  get{
   return DecryptFunc(this.Name);
  }
  }
}
```

serialize this class and send it to client